# javascript : comparing two arrays against each other challenge

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple javascript question I really could use some help on!
I am trying to figure out how to compare elements between arrays, and for the larger element to be compared again in the next loop.
Say we have Array A and Array B.

```
if(A[i] < B[i])
//do stuff

else if(B[i] < A[i])
//do stuff
```

My issue is that after I compare the elements at their index, I'd like the larger element to be compared in the next loop cycle.

So if A = [5,7,4]
and B = [2,8,5]

During the first loop 5 is compared to 2, 2 is smaller so stuff happens with it. In the next loop cycle I would like 5 to be compared with 8, and for stuff to now happen with 5. Next 8 is compared to 7, stuff happens with 7. Next 8 is compared to 4, stuff happens with 4. I haven't got a clue on how to accomplish this, your input is much much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a [merge algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm)?

Answer (score 1):

Define two iterator variables: aIdx, bIdx

Iterate both the array based on the imposed condition. At least one array is completely traversed in this iteration.

Now iterate the remaining (A or B) array.

```
var aIdx = 0;
var bIdx = 0;
// Iterate both array based on condition
while((aIdx < A.length) && (bIdx < B.length)) {
    if(A[aIdx] < B[bIdx]) {
       ++aIdx;
       // do stuff
    } else {
       ++bIdx;
       // do stuff
    }
}

// At this point, at least one array is completely traversed, now iterate the remaining array
while(aIdx < A.length) {
    ++aIdx;
    // do stuff
}
while (bIdx < B.length) {
    ++bIdx;
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: You sir may be on to something! I will check this!